# SQL Duplicate remover

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the folowing table:

```
**CDU_NomeFicheiro                  CDU_DataCriacao         CDU_Estado**
FicheiroBanco.xls                   2015-09-28 09:27:01.000   I
FicheiroBanco.xls                   2015-09-25 17:27:43.000   I
FicheiroBanco20150928v1.2.xls       2015-09-29 16:03:12.000   I
FicheiroBanco20150928teste11.xls    2015-09-28 09:45:15.000   I
FicheiroBanco20150928teste.xls      2015-09-28 09:28:36.000   I
FicheiroBanco20150928v1.2.xls       2015-09-29 16:03:11.000   E
```

And this is my query:

```
select distinct CDU_NomeFicheiro as 'Ficheiro'
, CDU_DataCriacao AS 'Data'      
from TDU_HistoricoIntegracoes 
where CDU_Estado = 'I' and CDU_NomeFicheiro is not null 
order by CDU_DataCriacao
```

And this is my result:

```
**Ficheiro                          Data**
FicheiroBanco.xls                   2015-09-25 17:27:43.000
FicheiroBanco.xls                   2015-09-28 09:27:01.000
FicheiroBanco20150928teste.xls      2015-09-28 09:28:36.000
FicheiroBanco20150928teste11.xls    2015-09-28 09:45:15.000
FicheiroBanco20150928v1.2.xls       2015-09-29 16:03:12.000
```

And this is the result I want:

```
*FicheiroBanco.xls                  2015-09-25 17:27:43.000* have to be removed
FicheiroBanco.xls                   2015-09-28 09:27:01.000
FicheiroBanco20150928teste.xls      2015-09-28 09:28:36.000
FicheiroBanco20150928teste11.xls    2015-09-28 09:45:15.000
FicheiroBanco20150928v1.2.xls       2015-09-29 16:03:12.000
```

It should show just the most recent row for each file, removing older duplicates with the same file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using SELECT DISTINCT, but for one of the columns you want to select one value from among several, you should be using MAX() and GROUP BY instead:

```
SELECT 
    CDU_NomeFicheiro AS 
    'Ficheiro', 
    MAX(CDU_DataCriacao) AS 'Data'
FROM 
    TDU_HistoricoIntegracoes
WHERE CDU_Estado = 'I'
    AND CDU_NomeFicheiro IS 
    NOT NULL
GROUP BY CDU_NomeFicheiro 
ORDER BY MAX(CDU_DataCriacao)
```

Edit: Since I added an aggregate function for CDU_DataCriacao, I should have also added the MAX() for the ORDER BY clause as well. I have made that change now. Does it work?

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, but i get the folowing error

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, but i get the folowing error
Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Column "TDU_HistoricoIntegracoes.CDU_DataCriacao" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @ClovisRibeiro Change it to `ORDER BY Data` that is the alias you use in the `SELECT`. I would use a different name like `maxData` or something

Answer (score 0):

this work:

```
SELECT CDU_NomeFicheiro as 'Ficheiro'
        ,MAX(CDU_DataCriacao) AS 'Data'      
    FROM [32851584_HistoricoIntegracoes]
    WHERE CDU_Estado = 'I' and CDU_NomeFicheiro is not null 
    GROUP BY CDU_NomeFicheiro
    ORDER BY Data
```